# How to regularize if zero values of model parameters do not give a "simple" model?

Tags: cross-validation, regularization, overfitting, train

I have a predictive model with a relative small number of model parameters (only 6). When I train the model on the training set and than validate the model on the validation set I have a strong indication of an over-fit (out-of-sample error is significantly larger than the in-sample error).

So, to solve the problem I can try to regularize by implying penalties on large values of the model parameters. However, in this particular case, I do not see a reason why zero values of the model parameters should provide a simple model. For example I have an angle as a model parameter and I do not see why zero degree is "better" than, let's say, 30 degree.

How to do a regularization in this case?

Comment: The regularization, or shrinkage towards zero applies to the *coefficients*, not the actual values of the explanatory variable. So the original values of the angles you are referring to would remain the same. Just the coefficient for the effect of a different angle is shrunk.

Comment: Just a note that: "out-of-sample error is significantly larger than the in-sample error" is not necessarily a sign of overfitting.

Answer (score 3):

**You can regularize relative to any set of parameter values you like.**  This can always be done by writing appropriate regularization code--but such an effort is usually unnecessary.  For models of a response $y$ in terms of variables $X$ that are linear in the sense

$$y = \beta_1 f_1(X) + \beta_2 f_2(X) + \cdots + \beta_p f_p(X) + \text{ error}\tag{1}$$

(for specified functions $f_1, \ldots, f_p$), suppose you consider the "simplest" possible value of parameter $\beta_i$ to be $\alpha_i$.  Rewrite model $(1)$ into the algebraically *and probabilistically* equivalent form

$$y - \alpha_1 f_1(X) - \cdots - \alpha_p f_p(X) = (\beta_1-\alpha_1) f_1(X)  + \cdots + (\beta_p-\alpha_p) f_p(X) + \text{ error}.$$

Because *you* specify the $\alpha_i$, you can compute the left hand side directly as part of data preprocessing.  Call its values $y^\prime$.  Proceed to fit the model

$$y^\prime = \gamma_1f_1(X) + \gamma_2 f_2(X) + \cdots + \gamma_p f_p(X) + \text{ error},$$

regularizing the coefficients (and likely shrinking them towards zero).  Simply set the model $(1)$ estimates to $\hat\beta_i = \hat\gamma_i + \alpha_i$ afterwards.  Any estimate that has been shrunk to $\hat\gamma_i=0$ will yield $\hat\beta_i=\alpha_i$, as planned.

---

Please note that **this works in part because subtracting terms like $\alpha_i f_i(X)$ from $y$ leaves the additive error term unaffected.**  It wouldn't do to, say, divide both sides by such terms, *because the error term would be divided by numbers that might vary from one case to the next.*  That would change the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any domain knowledge or ground truth data on the angle parameter, then you can come up with a probability distribution for the model (for example, modeling the angle distribution as a gaussian mixture), and then add $-\log P(\text{angle})$ as a penalty. The usual L1 or L2 penalty is a special case of this.

You could also try adding noise to the training data as a form of regularization, since a set of parameters which are more robust are less likely to overfit.